# SSL setup configuration in symfony 1.4

Tags: ssl, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a site with symfony 1.4, and installed the SSL certificate in the server, the home page works but when I click in any link I get an error 404. But if I use the Dev mode from symfony I am able to navigate through all the website... weird to me.

I tried to install the plugin sfSslRequirementPlugin - 2.0.0, when I enable it I get this error when loading the page: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for any page.

Any idea??

Comment: When you using the dev mode, are you also using SSL? Most of the time if there are no errors when using _dev, but there are when using non-dev, it's a caching issue. Make sure you've cleared the Symfony cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because of some code defects in **.htaccess** file. Can you please send me .htaccess file so that we can investigate more on this issue.

The error **net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** is because of .htacess as it is redirecting the page. I had faced the same issue once.